# How to configure webpack loader to process directory files without sub directories?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Config below will process all files in directory:

```
test: /\.html$/,
include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'directory'),
use: ['html-loader']
```

I can't understand how to make loader process only direct child files.

```
-directory
--file_level_1.html
...
--subdirectory
---file_level_2.html
...
```

The goal is to process level 1 files and omit level 2.

Comment: Check `include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '*')]`

Comment: try exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'directory/subdirectory'),